# How can combine dataset in R?

Tags: r

I think my question is very simple.

dat1<-seq(1:100)

dat2<-seq(1:100)

how can I combine dat1 and dat2 and make it look like

dat3<-seq(1:200)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you trying to combine vectors (which is what `seq()` produces) or data.frames?  There are different approaches depending on which data structures you're working with.

Comment: I think I am trying to combine vectors.

Comment: given your comment and the answer you selected, I think your example should read `dat2 <- seq(101:200)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you want to combine `dat1` and `dat2`? By rows or columns? I'd take a look at the help pages for `rbind()` (row bind) , `cbind()` (column bind), or`c()` which combines arguments to form a vector.

Comment: given the op has edited his Q to make `length(dat3) == 200`, it might be worth updating your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Let me start by a comment.

In order to create a sequence of number on can use the following syntax:

```
x <- seq(from=, to=, by=)
```

A shorthand for, e.g., `x <- seq(from=1, to=10, by=1)` is simply `1:10`. So, your notation is a little bit weird...

On the other hand, you can combine two or more vectors using the `c()` function. Let us say, for example, that `a <- c(1, 2)` and `b <- c(3, 4)`. Then `c <- c(a, b)` is the vector `(1, 2, 3, 4)`.

There exist similar functions to combine data sets: `rbind()` and `cbind()`.